# Compare 200.000 texts from DB

Tags: php, mysql, string, solr

I have a MySQL DB and a Solr instance, which is an exact copy of the MySQL DB.

We have a lot of duplicated texts (or texts who are simular for more then 80%). Those texts needs to be bundled from now on. In PHP i know there are very good functions to calculate those simulairities.

My problem is is as follows:

How can I smart (read: fast as possible) compare every new text, with an existing text in the DB? I dont think it is a good practice to read 200.000 records from the DB/Solr to compare one new item, and for the next thing, again.

Comment: Depends on your definition of *simular*.

Comment: I think he means an equality of at least 80%.

Comment: There is no such thing as *equality of at least 80%*. Two strings are either equal, or they are not equal.

Comment: What if you calculated the sha or md5 hash function of every text and stick that in a db table as a unique key.  See if you get any collisions (you may or may not) and see if any of those are in fact identical.  When you get a new "text", calculate its hash and compare. The problem with this idea is it will not alert to document pairs that are almost the same (i.e. extra whitespace, slight rewording).

Comment: @Paul That would require 100% similarity.

Comment: Yes, it would.  You could also find the greatest common substring between two texts, respecting word boundaries.  It is a pain, but I did it in Java once.  This is a little better but still somewhat fragile.  And it would involve N*(N-1)/2 comparisons.

Comment: In PHP are functions which calculate the diff/sims of a string in percentage(simular_text is on of them, but there are more.) I have to test which function is the best one, but thats is simething i can figure out. My problem is the amount of data. How do i, if i got a new text every few seconds, compare it with the DB/Solr, without breaking the rest of my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install a [MySQL plugin](https://github.com/jmcejuela/Levenshtein-MySQL-UDF) implementing the [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein) for MySQL and let the database do the comparison.

Comment: Ow nice one. I gonna check out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SOLR Dedupe](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Deduplication) which can

- prevent duplicate/similar documents going into your index
- or prevent duplicate/similar results returning from your searches
- or collapse duplicate/similar results on your search

For similar document detection you have to set your signatureClass to [TextProfileSignature](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TextProfileSignature)

However this is a very fuzzy algorithm and does not provide you an option to request "80% percent similar" To be honest I can't even think of a way to say these two documents are "80% similar" It is one of those statistics made on the spot via human perception I guess.

Still if the text that you want to compare is fairly long, than TextProfileSignature will produce great results.

Please read the [Implications and limitations on this page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TextProfileSignature)